# How to process listener of another fragment on MainActivity using bottom navigation view?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

Good morning everyone.

I want to process another fragment's listener in the `onCreate` method of `MainActivity`.

However, it didn't work.

`MainActivity` code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, null);
        Button searchBtn = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
        searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                outputText.setText("pressed");
                findDevice(); 
            }
        });
```

Here's what the layout resource folder currently contains:

[image: Directory view of layout resource folder]

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

So I did it on another fragment class.
But the button listener on the fragment still didn't work.

This is the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.

        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications, R.id.navigation_message)
                .build();

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }
}
```

And this is NotificationsFragment

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        notificationsViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NotificationsViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_notifications);
        notificationsViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });


        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
        MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container);
        outputText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);
        inputEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputEditText);
        sendBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sendBtn); 
        final Button searchBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);

        searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                outputText.setText("pressed");
                inputEditText.setText("pressed");
                findDevice();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to handle the action for a view that's found in a fragment in its enclosing activity rather than the fragment itself?   Typically the reason why we use fragments is to modularise the UI and not have everything done in the enclosing Activity.

Comment: normally you do that in the fragment only. and i think activity won't allow using another class's view to be injected

Comment: @Ryujin So I tried it on different activity class but it still didn't work

Comment: @RohitRawat So I tried it on different activity class but it still didn't work. Could you advise me? )

Comment: you need to declare searchButton object in the fragment class again before using it

Comment: The view objects that you declare in your layout can only receive events from the Activity or Fragment that's using them.  Simply inflating the same view layout from another class creates a different instance of those views.